# How to execute a sequence of terminal(Ubuntu) commands without pressing the return key

Tags: linux, ubuntu, administration

I've started to learn Ubuntu server administration for my own projects. For that purpose I created a config file, which I run on a new server instance for basic installation - for example to install git, nginx, etc. 
So, for example I copy into a terminal window 3 lines:

```
pip install flask
pip install gunicorn
pip install pymongo
```

and the first, and the second will be executed automatically, the the third one will wait for me))

It is possible somehow to execute all this sequence automatically, without pressing the return button for the last command?

Comment: Copy a blank line in addition to the three lines!

Answer (score 2):

You can write a shell script with the following contents and save as myscript.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
pip install flask
pip install gunicorn
pip install pymongo
```

Give it execute permissions by:
    chmod u+x myscript.sh
Execute it by:
    ./myscript.sh

Answer (score 1):

you'd better do a bash script like :

```
#!/bin/sh
pip install flask
pip install gunicorn
pip install pymongo
```

then made it executable with `chmod +x script.sh` and run `./script.sh`

Comment: Hmm..., It makes sense. Thank, I am going to try it right now

Comment: feel free to validate this answer if it solves your problem ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate commands in one line using semi-colon and then copy/paste all the line together:

pip install flask; pip install gunicorn; pip install pymongo

Comment: Thanks, that is good for a small amount of commandsd. But I wrote an example - in real in that config file there are a lot of strings) So, in this case it is not suitable approach.